# recoding variables using case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

```
starwars_ %$% table(sex, gender)
```

[image]

and now I have to use the function case_when() to recode the category “none” of sex into “male” if gender is “masculine” and into “female” if gender is “feminine”. Make sure that the categories of sex other than “none” are not converted to NA by specifying the TRUE ~ ... argument. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

starwars %>% 
  mutate(sex = case_when(gender == "feminine" ~ "female",
                         gender == "masculine" ~ "male",
                         TRUE ~ sex)) %$% 
  table(sex, gender)
#>         gender
#> sex      feminine masculine
#>   female       17         0
#>   male          0        66
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>